# Euclidean algorithm - What am I doing? python john zelle

Tags: python

The greatest common divisor (GCD) of two values can be computed using Euclid's algorithm. Starting with the values m and n, we repeatedly apply the formula: n, m = m, n%m until m is 0. At that point, n is the GCD of the original m and n. Write a program that finds the GCD of two numbers using this algorithm.

I am using-
What am I doing wrong?

```
def gcd(m, n):
  m=int(input("Enter the number for m:"))
  n=int(input("Enter the number for n:"))
    while m!=n 
     if m>n:
        m=m−n
     else:
        n=n−m
     return m
```

Comment: What is `n'm`? Did you mean `n % m`?

Comment: Yes sorry. The formula: n, m = m, n%m until m is 0.

Comment: Quick note: typos on the 3rd line: enter number for **n** (but irrelevant to the code anyway). Suppose ``m=2, n=3``, then ``n=3-2``, it makes ``n=1``, but ``m`` stays the same as the original input values.

Comment: Thank you! Why wouldnt I need the input? (Im new to this lol). Remove the user inputs but how would I know which numbers im pulling from ?

Comment: @KassidiTurner your function is already getting values of m and n passed to it via the funtion's input. So basically you can assume that your function already has values for m and n, and you don't need to get it from within the function itself.

Comment: Well, then your code _doesn't_ match your algorithm. Where did you copy this code from? Did it mention the limitations of the code? What inputs are you using? Why do you pass arguments to your function but then overwrite those with more user inputs?

Comment: Also, why do you `return m` at the end of the first `while` iteration? **Indentation matters** in python.

Comment: @KassidiTurner the inputs should be outside of the function, or if it is in the function, it's enough to write ``def gcd():``

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I used the algorithm below so im not sure. I am still learning but on pycharm my indentation is correct  its possible when rewriting on here I had errors.                                                           
  gcd(a, b)
    while a ≠ b 
        if a > b−
            a := a − b
        else
            b := b − a
    return a

Comment: @Karina So I did that about "def gcd(m,n):" and it would ask  me for the inputs but it wouldn't go through the function. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ah I just saw your other comment. That make sense. I was thinking before the function

Comment: Add a breakpoint and run line by line while looking at the watch window to see how the variables change and what is wrong with your algorithm or implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you `return m` at the end of the *first iteration* of the `while` loop. You need to wait until the `while m != n` ends before returning.

While you're at it, lose the `input()` statements. You already gave your function the values of `m` and `n` that you want to use *as arguments to the function*.

```
def gcd(m, n):
    while m!=n 
        if m>n:
            m=m−n
        else:
            n=n−m
    return m
```

To run this, you'd ask for the values of `m` and `n` *before* you call the function, and then use those values.

```
a=int(input("Enter the first number:"))
b=int(input("Enter the second number:"))

print(gcd(a, b))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help